# Highlight chart title in Word Document

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to highlight Chart title text (few characters).

```vb
ReplaceWhat = "Before"
ReplaceWith = "After"
If chrt.HasTitle Then
    pos = InStr(chrt.ChartTitle.Characters.Text, ReplaceWhat)
    If pos > 0 Then
        chrt.ChartTitle.Characters(pos, Len(ReplaceWhat)).Text = ReplaceWith
        chrt.ChartTitle.Characters(pos, Len(ReplaceWhat)).Font.Bold = msoTrue
    End If
End If
```

I am able to find and replace Chart title text and also able to make Bold.

For changing text color

```
chrt.ChartTitle.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 0)
```

Not found any solution for highlighting title.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:

```
Range("A1:A5").HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
```

Theres an Property of Range called Range.HighlightColorIndex = //wdColorIndex//

Comment: I wanted to Highlight Chart title not excel cell characters, I think this will work for excel

Comment: Like my previous post I checked the Microsoft Documentation and looked for a Highlight Property of the CharTitle object, and it seems it cannot be highlighted.
Refer to: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.charttitle(object)